# How to automatically open a folder in WSL for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can we customize `.vscode/settings.json` such that whenever we open that folder in VS Code, it will be opened in WSL environment?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that adding `"window.restoreWindows": "all"` to your `settings.json` can work. You could also try creating a workspace.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. Could you provide some insight on how to create a eternal workspace?